# can't use string in function at postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have some problem with postgresql functions.
My table name is people and name is text and year is integer.

I like to write a function like this:

```
create function add() returns void as '
insert into people(name, year) VALUES ('danilo', 12)

' LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I can't insert string, like danilo.

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "danilo"

I tried

```
...
insert into people(name, year) VALUES ( \'danilo\', 12)
...
```

but doesn't works.

this works perfectly:

```
...insert into people( year) VALUES ( 12)...
```

and this too:

```
create function add(text) returns void as '
insert into people(name, year) VALUES ($1, 12)

' LANGUAGE SQL;

select add('danilo');
```

but how can I do something like:

```
...
insert into people(name, year) VALUES ('danilo', 12)
...
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer:

Use ''danilo'', double the '

Escaping single quotes ' by doubling them up ''

```
create function add() returns void as '
insert into people(name, year) VALUES (''danilo'', 12)

' LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your case is good example, why PostgreSQL has custom string separators - symbol `$some$`. Custom string separator should be used in pair.

```
postgres=# select $_$Hello$_$;
 ?column? 
----------
 Hello
(1 row)
```

There are no issues with apostrophes

```
postgres=# select $_$He'llo$_$;
 ?column? 
----------
 He'llo
(1 row)
```

So your code should to look like

```
create function add(text)
returns void as $$
insert into people(name, year) VALUES ('Hello', 12)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape with double single quote

```
create function add() returns void as '
insert into people(name, year) VALUES (''danilo'', 12)
' LANGUAGE SQL;
```